# How do I split a stream to handle elements in different ways?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm using code like this to process a file consisting of multiple lines:

```
BufferedReader reader = ...
reader.lines().forEach(Same common Action)
```

This works fine as long as every line needs to be handled the same way. But sometimes there may be several different actions.

For example, let's say the first line is a header and the other lines are content. For the first line I want to perform `Action1`, and for the others I want `Action2`.

In Java 7 style I'd do something like this:

```
String line;
boolean first = true;
while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    if (first) {
        action1(line);
        first = false;
    } else {
        action2(line);
    }
}
```

But that's complex and ugly, and it is not using streams at all. How can I do that in an idiomatic way using Java 8 streams?

Comment: `findFirst()` in stream should help!

Comment: @Yash and what does he do with the other lines?

Comment: You can put the `if` into the `forEach` as normal

Comment: @Lino use the stream again?

Comment: @Yash `findFirst` is a terminal operation, which means he must get a new stream, which would start from the beginning again

Comment: `findFirst()` will stop right after the first iteration. So the complexity will still be O(n)

Comment: @Yash but you're still getting a stream 2 times. which isn't that handy

Comment: @Lino agreeing with you. Just saw Eugene's answer. It's a better fit.

Answer (score 21):

```
Spliterator<String> sp = reader.lines().spliterator();    

sp.tryAdvance(YourConsumer)
sp.forEachRemaning(DifferentConsumer)
```

Comment: or `if(sp.tryAdvance(YourConsumer)) sp.forEachRemaning(DifferentConsumer);`. But this only works, if either, you don’t have intermediate stream operations or if they are common between the header processing and the ordinary line processing. But in case of `BufferedReader`, there is [a much simpler solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47207171/2711488); use a stream only for the ordinary lines, not for the sole header line…

Answer (score 5):

Don’t make your life so hard:

```
String header = reader.readLine();
if(header != null) {
    action1(header);
    reader.lines().forEach(line -> action2(line));
}
```

or if you have already existing actions implementing `Consumer<String>`:

```
String header = reader.readLine();
if(header != null) {
    action1.accept(header);
    reader.lines().forEach(action2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this with `AtomicBoolean`

```
AtomicBoolean first = new AtomicBoolean(true);
reader.lines()
      .forEach(s -> first.getAndSet(false) ? FirstConsumer : SecondConsumer);
```